# Java MySQLSyntaxError

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm building a program around a MySQL database using JDBC Driver.
I'm stuck at this point.

```
loginWindow lW = new loginWindow();
try {
   PreparedStatement pst = connHandler.conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM   '" + lW.fieldUname.getText() + "''");             


   ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
   table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

    } catch (SQLException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have a connHandler class which is holding the connection method and the Connection (named: "conn") variable. I assume I have some problems with my query.

The error that I'm getting:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''''' at line 1
```

I would really appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use that

```
 "SELECT * FROM '" + lW.fieldUname.getText() + " ' "
```

you have two of " ' " that at the end

Comment: for mysql I suggest to use `\`` instead of `'`

Comment: I just fixed his sql statement, he is free to use whatever he wants.

Comment: @Lashane and I agree with you, he should use `(back quotes) to wrap Strings in sql statement.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM `" + lW.fieldUname.getText() + " ` " 
WORKS like a charm :) 
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got it working. With the help of

> kaan yılmaz
>
> Lashane

```
"SELECT * FROM `" + lW.fieldUname.getText() + " ` "
```

So, I have used  ` instead of '.

Thanks. :)